# Picking the right database technique for file storage and search

Tags: sql, database, laravel, pdf

for a personal project I am searching for the "most suitable" database engine to hit the following key issues

- need to store large amounts of single different document files (PDF)
- need to perform full-text search onto PDF (for this I plan to use OCR and save the processed data/metadata additionally to the database)
- need to get pieces/chunks of the saved documents (for example from a specific year) and show a preview of lots of them within a nice web UI
- as much performance as possible

Up to now I did work a lot with SQL (MySql) and have some theoretical knowledge about other systems (MemCached, Redis, PostgreSQ, MongoDb). But I`ve never used them in combination and never hit the point WHEN they should be used for WHAT exactly or how they can be combined.

I think especially for a project like this it`s very important to select the right engine from beginning not to hit performance issues later.
So especially to all experienced developers out there, what would be your favourite choiche for this kind  of (I gues SQL may not be the only right solution) ?
Or at the end will it be better to store files within filesystem and keep only metadata in database ?

BTW my planned API backend for this is Laravel 7+, frontend will be Vue 2+.

Thank you very much !

Comment: I would personally use something like Elastic Search. I would parse (OCR) and store metadata, to be able to search them with Elastic Search.

Comment: Hi, i have already seen that but wasn`t sure if it is what I was looking for. As I realized Elastic has its own storage backend ? Thanks.